# Need DB Table name for multiple queries executed using spring JDBCTemplate

Tags: spring, concurrency, executorservice, jdbctemplate

I am executing multiple queries concurrently and retrieving the results. But, the queries belong to multiple tables so, when resultset is retrieved, it is difficult to identify that a resultset belong to which table.
Can anyone help here as to how to identify the table names for each query resultset?

I tried below code but table name is blank!!!!

```
    public static void getColumnNames(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    if (rs == null) {
      return;
    }
    // get result set meta data
    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
    int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

    // get the column names; column indexes start from 1
    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns + 1; i++) {
      String columnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);
      // Get the name of the column's table name
      String tableName = rsMetaData.getTableName(i);
      System.out.println("column name=" + columnName + " table=" + tableName + "");
    }
  }
```

I am calling this method like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<ResultSet>() {

@Override
public ResultSet extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException,
                DataAccessException {
        getColumnNames(resultSet);
        return resultSet;
    }

});
```

Please advise, what is done wrong here? :(

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong here. The problem is caused by the method itself in connection with your DBMS or your JDBC driver, respectively.

See this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName%28int%29) please. 'table name or "" if not applicable' suggests that in your case the DBMS/driver does not provide the required information, causing the method to return an empty string.

I'm afraid, you'll have to find another way to detect which query the result originated from.

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be a restriction from my DBMS. Will try to find an alternate way. Thanks Once again.

Comment: Your welcome. Please don't forget to click 'accepting this answer' in order to mark it as finished.